# STM32VLDiscovery Timer Interrupt HardFault c

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, stm32

I've tried to write a short program using the stm32 timer interrupt on the stm32f100rbt6 on a STM32VLDiscovery board.

This is the code I have so far (main.c):

```
static inline void initGPIO() {
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef init;
    init.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    init.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    init.GPIO_Pin = 0xFFFF;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &init);
}

static inline void initTimer3() {
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn);
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;
    TIM3->SR = 0;
    TIM3->ARR = 0xFFFF;
    TIM3->PSC = 0xFFFF;
    TIM3->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
    //same problem when I enable the IRQ here
}

int main(void) {
    SCB->CCR |= SCB_CCR_STKALIGN;
    SystemInit();

    initGPIO();

    GPIOC->ODR = 0xFFFF;

    initTimer3();

    for (;;) {
        GPIOC->BSRR = ~(TIM3->CNT >> 8) & 0x7F;
        GPIOC->BRR = (TIM3->CNT >> 8) & 0x7F;
    }
}

void TIM3_IRQHandler() {
    TIM3->SR = 0;
    //GPIOC->ODR = 0xCC;
}

void HardFault_Handler() {
    GPIOC->BRR = 0x100;
    while (1)
        ;
}
```

It should call the IRQHandler everytime the timer overflows. When I don't enable the NVIC, then the program runs normally, just writing a part of the timer value to GPIOC. But as soon as I enable the NVIC, the program HardFaults, as soon as the initTimer3 function is called.

What I've tried so far:

- Moving the NVIC_EnableIRQ line somewhere else in the function

  - Still get the same problem
- Adding a delay before calling the initTimer3 function

  - Everything before the initTimer3 function gets executed correctly, as soon as the init function is called, the program hardfaults.
- Using a Different Timer

  - I already tried using TIM7 and TIM6

**Update**

Setting the STKALIGN bit does not change anything either. The HardFault happens as soon as the Interrupt is activated.

Comment: Should you not be enabling the interrupt AFTER configuring the timer registers?  Does the timer need to be powered up?

Comment: I already tried enabling the interrupt after the timer configuration, also tried enabling it just before writing CEN bit to high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another common problem:

The interrupt routine name must  much this one in the startup files.
For example in the code generated by the Cube MX the vector table is defined in the startup_stm32f103xb.s file.
The timer interrupts routines are:

```
  .word TIM1_BRK_IRQHandler
  .word TIM1_UP_IRQHandler
  .word TIM1_TRG_COM_IRQHandler
  .word TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
  .word TIM2_IRQHandler
  .word TIM3_IRQHandler
  .word TIM4_IRQHandler
```

Check in your files what names are used in the vector table.

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem, turnes out that because I did use the stdPeriph library and not HAL, so I didn't use Cube MX. Almost all of those table entries where 0 because of that.

Comment: I do not use HAL but project templates generated by the Cube are much better. I import the project, then remove  the HAL files and definitions.

Answer (score -1):

You have the HF probably because the stack when invoking  the interrupt routine is not aligned . F1xx family has hardware stack alignment off by default and startup  or user app has to enable it. Alternatively  you can force a proper alignment  by using the proper attribute.

[image]

Comment: I think you are wrong here. The STKALIGN bit is set to 8 bytes by default in the Cortex-M core at reset so this is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: No you are wrong. In stm32f1xx this bit is zero by default. You should  have been checking  it before commenting.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation which says this? The Cortex-M3 documentation, as well as the STM32F10xx programming manual both clearly show this bit is set to 8 byte alignment on reset. I did double check this before posting (Reset value of CCR register is 0x0000 0200)

Comment: @RealtimeRik it is called Programming manual. Why do you comment my answer if you even did not read about it. See above

Comment: @RealtimeRik - LOL.  Read the full sentences. 0x0000 0200 is for the F2xxx series not F1xxx

Comment: Ok, you are correct. However I did read the entire section of the "Programming Manual". If you look at Rev 3 the documentation is wrong. This was the one I had lying around from when I was working on this.

Comment: @RealtimeRik This version does not exists anymore. Is it 4+ years old? It is good **always** to read the current version of the documentation.

Comment: I tried setting the STKALIGN bit at the beginning of main, but I still get the same problem. HardFault as soon as the interrupt should get executed. Also found another slight annoyance, apparently the UIF Flag is set after I reset the controller, even though I set TIM3->SR = 0, thats the reason why it originally crashed as soon as the interrupt is configured.

Comment: Another very possible problem. The name of your interrupt routine does not match the one in your vector table. Go to your startup file and see what the correct name is. Some startups do not define all vector table entries.